# How to make a desktop notification when making a new post on my site?

Tags: javascript, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3

I have a blog of recipes and I want to send desktop notification whenever I post a new recipe. I wonder how I can do it and incorporate Laravel (if needed)?

My JavaScript is not that great, but this is the code I have so far. Asking permission from the user, and it is working fine:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
});
```

And making a new notification like so:

```
    var notificationOptions= {
      body: 'The body of the notification',
};
    new Notification("Hi, there is a new recipe!", notificationOptions);
```

The code in my controller that is responsible for passing data to the view (not really sure if that is related, bit just in case):

```
public function slug(Request $request, $slug)

{
        $post = Post::whereSlug($slug)->first();
        $time=$post->created_at->format('d-m-Y');
        return view('slug', compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: Looks like the javascript part is half way there. All you need is to broadcast the creation of a Post to your front-end. Try to watch this video: https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-laravel-echo I think it has everything you want.

Comment: I will try and will say here. Thanks

Comment: @HelderLucas Well, i have checked that out, but its not suitable for me. i need to use a whole js framework for that, and that's not very smart for such a small thing in my opinion. Any other way?

Comment: You just need the laravel-echo js package. In the video he is using it vuejs for the demonstration :)